# Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using to loop one is `foreach` and another is `for loop`. Foreach loop used for `system.Data` and `for loop` used for Data which is Array. I am trying match the property of both object If match than it you pass value to my Oracle Procedure to save data. Here is my code:

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow dz in ViewBag.MenuData2.Rows)
                {
                    ViewBag.comp = @dz["mnud_text"];

                    for (int i =0; i<data.Length;i++ )
                    {
                        if (ViewBag.comp == data[i])
                        {
                            if (@dz["chk"].ToString() == "0" || @dz["umnu_oid"].ToString() == "N")
                            {
                                 actv = "1";
                            }

                            string user_id = data[i];
                            ds = new DataSet();
                            ds = _clsDataAccess.update_menu_permission("00003", ViewBag.comp.ToString(), actv,"N", "00002");
                        }
                    }

                }
```

and the procedure is :

```
public void update_menu_permission(string user_id, string menu_id, string actv, string oid, string euser)
{
    conn = new OracleConnection(clsConnection.ConnectionSave);
    conn.Open();
    if (oid == "N")
    {
        strComm = "insert into thlhr.t_umnu (oid, umnu_mnud, umnu_user, umnu_actv, iuser, euser) values "
            + "(:oid, :umnu_mnud, :umnu_user, :umnu_actv, :iuser, :euser)";

        cmd = new OracleCommand(strComm, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("oid", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "UMNU" + user_id.ToUpper() + menu_id.ToUpper();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("umnu_mnud", OracleType.VarChar).Value = menu_id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("umnu_user", OracleType.VarChar).Value = user_id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("umnu_actv", OracleType.VarChar).Value = actv;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("iuser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = euser;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("euser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = euser; 
    }
    else
    {
        strComm = "update thlhr.t_umnu set umnu_actv = :umnu_actv, euser = :euser where oid ='" + oid + "'";

        cmd = new OracleCommand(strComm, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("umnu_actv", OracleType.VarChar).Value = actv;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("euser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = euser;
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

when I am passing value i am having this error `"Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'"` please help me to sort this problem. let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with the following line:

```
ds = _clsDataAccess.update_menu_permission("00003", ViewBag.comp.ToString(), actv,"N", "00002");
```

The update method doesnt return anything.

Also, it is a good practice to wrap code with using blocks.

**Update:**

You really dont need:

```
ds = new DataSet();
ds = _clsDataAccess.update_menu_permission("00003", ViewBag.comp.ToString(), actv,"N", "00002");
```

Just call:

```
_clsDataAccess.update_menu_permission("00003", ViewBag.comp.ToString(), actv,"N", "00002");
```

Comment: Thank You for quick replay. Could you fix this for me plzzz. I have wasted lots of time for that.

Comment: `ViewBag.comp.ToString()` I am getting error from here may be

Comment: Whats the return type of comp?

Comment: Hi, @Gauravsa . I just a made little mistake that I did not remove `ds` from code. Now its working perfectly. Thank You

Comment: I am trying to mark the question but My reputation is too low too mark it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242298/how-to-handle-dynamic-checkbox-in-controller-asp-net-mvc-5 

I recently post this question would you help plz